# Using Selenium, how to click a radio button based on associated label

Tags: c#, html, selenium, automation

I'm using Selenium in C#, and I need to be able to specify which radio button on a website to click based on the text of the label that is associated with that radio button. I need to be able to pass that text in as a parameter. Here is a sample of what the code for the radio buttons looks like (this is for three buttons):

```
<input id="radSelect152_222_1369" class="bgRadioNotChecked" type="radio" onclick="BGQ.Ajax.SelectAnswer(this, '152','1369','3', '547');" value="1369" onfocus="BGQ.View.setLastElement(true);" name="radSelect152_222">
<label class="inline" for="radSelect152_222_1369">Watermelon</label>

<input id="radSelect152_222_1370" class="bgRadioNotChecked" type="radio" onclick="BGQ.Ajax.SelectAnswer(this, '152','1370','3', '547');" value="1370" onfocus="BGQ.View.setLastElement(true);" name="radSelect152_222">
<label class="inline" for="radSelect152_222_1370">Papaya</label>

<input id="radSelect152_222_1371" class="bgRadioNotChecked" type="radio" onclick="BGQ.Ajax.SelectAnswer(this, '152','1371','3', '547');" value="1371" onfocus="BGQ.View.setLastElement(true);" name="radSelect152_222">
<label class="inline" for="radSelect152_222_1371">Mango</label>
```

I want to be able to specify "Mango" in an Excel input file (I have all the file input stuff working fine) and have Selenium click the associated radio button. One approach that I read that I've been trying is to do the following:

1. Find the element that has the target text ("Mango") as its text
2. Get the FOR attribute from that element
3. Find the input that has an id equal to that FOR attribute
4. Click that input element.

Problem is, I'm pretty new to Selenium and can't quite figure the syntax for how to do these four steps. Can someone show me the way, with specific code examples? Also, or alternatively, is there a better/smarter way to do this? If so, please be specific.

I've included here the method I've started to write, in which I pass in the target text. I know it's wrong (especially in the By.XPath part).

```
    public void ClickRadioButtonByLabelText(string labelText)
    {
        // (1) Find the element that has the label text as its text
        IWebElement labelForButton = commondriver.FindElement(By.XPath(//label[text()='labelText']));
        // (2) Get the FOR attribute from that element
        string forAttribute 
        // (3) Find the input that has an id equal to that FOR attribute
        // (4) Click that input element
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not click the Label? As they're connected by the `for` attribute that should select the associated check box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options.

**Option 1 - do it all within a single XPath query**

The XPath query would be:

```
//input[@id=//label[text()='TestCheckBox']/@for]
```

That is, get `input` that has an `id` which comes from the `for` attribute from a `label` that has the `text` of "TestCheckBox"

**Option 2 - get the attribute from the label and then find the element in seperate steps**

```
public void ClickRadioButtonByLabelText(string labelText)
{
    // (1) Find the element that has the label text as its text
    IWebElement labelForButton = commondriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[text()='labelText']"));

    // (2) Get the FOR attribute from that element
    string forAttribute = labelForButton.GetAttribute("for");

    // (3) Find the input that has an id equal to that FOR attribute
    IWebElement radioElement = commondriver.FindElement(By.Id(forAttribute));

    // (4) Click that input element
    radioElement.Click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but Option 1 didn't work (I don't remember the error, as I moved on to Option 2.) Also, Option 2 isn't working. Is the XPath syntax correct in the first line? Is there something missing? I keep getting a no such element exception that says "Unable to find element with xpath == //label[text()='Other']" ("Other" is the text I'm searching for, and I see it right there on the page between the <label> tags when I use Firebug.)

Comment: Option 1 should work - please retry it and tell me the error, the second issue try `//label[contains(., 'Other')]`. I am just using the XPath you gave in the first post, I assumed you had already verified it working.

Comment: Thanks; Option 2 works now, using your new suggestion. Option 1 is still not working. My statement is: IWebElement radio = commondriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id=//label[text()='Other']/@for]")); and I'm getting this error: Unable to find element with xpath == //input[@id=//label[text()='Other']/@for]

Comment: @johnnyb1970, try replacing your XPath with the one I suggested above. Do you still get the same issue afterwards? (I know option 2 has worked but both of them should!). Also please accept the answer if you are happy with it.

Comment: I should also note that the labels have a leading space within their text, like this: <label> Other</label>. I don't know why; I assume the developers did this to add more space between the label and the radio button. But it doesn't seem to matter whether I add that space or not in my xpath statement. I just can't seem to get the text() function to work. Is it possible to use the contains() function such that it will match the target text exactly, as opposed to just text that "contains" the supplied text? That is, can I get it to behave like an "equals()" function? Or does one already exist?

Comment: Yes, Option 1 works now, using the new XPath you provided. It just seems to be text() that I'm having an issue with, but I can live with that. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, that would be it. You will have to force the whitespaces to be stripped using `normalize-space`. `//label[normalize-space(text())='Other']` or `//label[normalize-space(.)='Other']`